# Handling streaming from OBS in PHP

Tags: php, video, stream

I am interested in outputting an OBS (Open Broadcast Software) stream to my browser via a `<video>` tag. I am unsure of how to go about doing this. I am very familiar with PHP and was wondering if it would be possible to capture the stream data and simultaneously output at the same time via PHP, or if I require some other technology.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.12891/

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what I was looking for.